# MySQL - Select rows where column value is only 0, group by another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Example table:

```
ID, foreign_id, status
```

The `ID` is **unique**, the `foreign_id` is not. Example rows:

```
1, 1111, 0  
2, 2222, 0  
3, 3333, 1
4, 1111, 1
5, 4444, 0
```

What I want to select is unique `foreign_id`'s that only have the status as 0. If it has a status as 0 but another row with the same foreign ID has a status as 1, don't select that `foreign_id`. Expected output:

```
1, 2222, 0
5, 4444, 0
```

I can select where `status = 0` and group by `foreign_id`, but that will just select the row where status is 0 even though there may be another row with the same `foreign_id` and status as 1.

```
SELECT ID, foreign_id 
FROM table 
WHERE status = 0 
GROUP BY foreign_id
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GROUP_CONCAT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) and `DISTINCT` clause, we **group** all the unique statuses against a `foreign_id`. Now inside the `HAVING` clause, we just need to filter out only those `foreign_id`, where unique statuses is `'0'` only.

Try the following:

```
SELECT ID, foreign_id, status, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT status) as statuses 
FROM table 
GROUP BY foreign_id 
HAVING statuses = '0'
```

Comment: Nice idea using GROUP_CONCAT - but the query won't return the relevant data without a `GROUP BY foreign_id`, and then you lose the id - hence your query doesn't filter the right  foreign_id records and doesn't output the required attributes

Comment: @symcbean my query has a `GROUP BY` clause in it. Kindly clarify further.

Comment: Try running it - see what happens to the ID - either you'll get an error if your DBMS is configured to use strict syntax or it will report the last value for 'id' it sees - OP wanted all the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

(I edited this to demonstrate that it works and to clarify some things):

What you're probably interested in is the HAVING statement.

You can use a HAVING statement *after* your GROUP BY. Here is a pretty good explanation:
https://www.dofactory.com/sql/having

In short, what the HAVING statement does is let you filter on your data in that returns as a result of your GROUP BY expression.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
     foreign_id, MAX(status) AS status
FROM
     myTable
GROUP BY 
     foreign_id
HAVING 
     MAX(status) = 0
```

Here is an example of it working (tested in a basic MS Access file):

[image]

Then I entered this code:

[image]

And I got these results:

[image]

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select foreign_id, max(status) as status
from t
group by foreign_id
having max(status) = 0;
```

Basically, you need to do the test *after* the `group by`.

If you want the complete rows, use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.foreign_id = t.foreign_id and t2.status <> 0
                 );
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should be aggregating the data, but there are lots of potential issues with this. But before we get to that, you have stated that you want the original records in the output - not the consolidated data - the simplest solution is to use 2 queries - one to identify the foreign_ids with only status=0 and one to get the corresponding rows

```
SELECT r.*
FROM examples r
JOIN ( SELECT s.foreign_id, MAX(s.status)
  FROM examples s
  GROUP BY s.foreign_id
  HAVING MAX(s.status)=0
) t
ON r.foreign_id=t.foreign_id
```

Alternatively you could get the foreign_ids where status!=0 and exclude those in the second query - which might be more efficient depending on the distribution of your data.

Where this comes unstuck is in the case where "status" < 0. The output will include these rows (potentially the same can happen with SUM()). There are several ways to address this, you could SUM(ABS(status)) or SUM(IF(status=0,0,1)) for example. As Madhur suggests you could also GROUP_CONCAT(status) and check that the output of the column is only '0'.

But I suspect you are about to tell me that status cannot be negative (or null?) as it is a [nominal number](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/cardinal-ordinal-nominal.html). If that's the case then you are using the wrong data type - you should be using an ENUM. If that is the case, then you can't apply SUM() or MAX() to an ENUM but you can still use the SUM(IF(status=?,0,1)) or GROUP_CONCAT() methods.

Hence....

```
SELECT r.*
FROM examples r
JOIN ( SELECT s.foreign_id, SUM(IF(status=0,0,1))
  FROM examples s
  GROUP BY s.foreign_id
  HAVING SUM(IF(status=0,0,1))=0
) t
ON r.foreign_id=t.foreign_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function

```
select * from t where foreign_id in (
     select foreign_id
        from t
        group by foreign_id
        having min(status) = 0
       ) and status!=1
```